# Unexpected result using statechart to model truck deliveries?

Tags: anylogic

I am building a model where trucks leave the main distributor to make deliveries to several customers along a route before returning back to the distributor when it is empty. I have created a "Truck" agent which models the truck's behavior as it goes from the distributor, from customer to customer, and then back to the distributor. In my model, I want the trucks to be going on a trip for no longer than 20 hours before heading back.

To do this, I created a statechart in my truck agent, yet it isn't working the way I expected it to with my code. Here is a screenshot of the states within my statechart, pictured here:

[image: Statechart]

I have the code

```
startTime = time(HOUR);
```

on my "atDistributor" state, with the transitions between atDistributor and after prepareToLeave at 1 day, and 0 hours, respectively. My code for the movingToCustomer block is as follows:

```
client = getNearestAgent(customers);
if ((time(HOUR) - startTime) < 20)
    moveTo(client);
else
    moveTo(main.distributor);
```

There's an unloading time of 30 minutes, and the branch going back up to movingToCustomer has the condition of

```
customers.size() > 0
```

and movingBackToNewton has the entry action

```
moveTo(main.Newton);
```

When I run the model, however, I look at trip times for individual trucks, and they are greater than 20 hours. This leads me to believe there must be some sort of error in my code or logic, though I don't know where to look.

Comment: Please show us all the relevant code to this and some small sample data set.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I included all the code in my statechart, was there any other code you still need? I'm not sure if I can share the dataset, but it contains around 300 points with an order identification number, order weight, and order location (city, zip, state.)

Comment: just something small to test `if ((time(HOUR) - startTime) < 20)` Because I don't know what those numbers are

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I know entirely what you mean -- time(TIME_UNIT) is listed in AnyLogic help as returning the current model time, so I put that code block to compare the startTime which I established as the time when the truck was at the distributor.

Comment: Try this function `differenceInCalendarUnits( timeUnit, time1, time2 )`  do you get the same results? https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Ffunctions%2FdifferenceInCalendarUnits.html&cp=3_2_3_4

Comment: Also can you set up an online example at something like https://javafiddle.leaningtech.com/

Comment: Hello, I tried that new function, but it didn't change anything. I'm not sure if I could set up a Java simulation since there are a lot of parameters in other agents that are used in the statechart.

Answer (score 0):

This is the potential problem you have:

This is your code for movingToCustomer:

```
client = getNearestAgent(customers);
if ((time(HOUR) - startTime) < 20)
    moveTo(client);
else
    moveTo(main.distributor);
```

This means that if the time is over 20, it will go back to the distributor... but when it arrives to your distributor, it goes to the state "unload" and then it goes to the branch to ask the question `customers.size() > 0`

And since that is true, it goes back to the movingToCustomer state

This statechart is conceptually wrong.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. Can you explain how I might be able to fix it? Thanks again!